# I need help finding the $\lim_{x\to 0}\sin{\frac{1}{x}\cos{\frac{1}{x}}}$ or proving it does not exist

Tags: real-analysis

I do not really know where to start other than plugging in $0$ for $x$ which is undefined. I cant even think of a way to use the limit definition. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: because they are periodic functions, and you don't know what will be the value of $\sin(\infty)$. All you can say is, it lies in $[-1,1]$. Hence it is called oscillatory limit.

Comment: Try to plug $x=\frac{1}{2\pi n}$ and $x=\frac{1}{2\pi n+\pi/2}$ where $n$ is positive integer.

Comment: @richrow It's the right approach, but both are $0$. The second one should be maybe $\frac1{2\pi n+\pi/4}$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: it's $\frac{1}{2}\sin \frac{2}{x}$ and argument tends to $\infty$

Answer (score 2):

If $x=\dfrac{1}{2n\pi}$ for integer $n$ then $\sin{\frac{1}{x}\cos{\frac{1}{x}}}=0\times1= 0$.  As $n\to \infty$ you have $x \to 0$ and the subsequence stays at $0$

If $x=\dfrac{1}{(2n+\frac14)\pi}$ then $\sin{\frac{1}{x}\cos{\frac{1}{x}}}=\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\times\frac1{\sqrt{2}} =\frac12$.  As $n\to \infty$ you have $x \to 0$ and the subsequence stays at $\frac12$

Since the two subsequences have different limits, the original expression does not converge as $x \to 0$.  It actually looks like

[image: chart of sin(1/x)*cos(1/x)]

Answer (score 0):

If $x = \frac {4}{(2n+1)\pi},$ i.e. $\frac 1x = \frac {\pi}{4} + 2n\pi$ then $\sin \frac {1}{x}\cos \frac {1}{x} = \frac 12$

If $x = \frac {4}{(2n+3) \pi}$ then $f(x) = -\frac 12$

For any $\delta > 0$ there are values of $x$ such that $|x| < \delta$ and $f(x) = \frac 12$ and $f(x) = -\frac 12$

Set  $\epsilon < \frac 12.$  And, by the definition of limits, the limit does not exist.